# clicking on body except specific element of specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
  if( $(e.target).closest("#myid").length > 0 ) {
    return false;
  }
  alert('clicked');
});
```

```css
#myid{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="myid">
    something <br>
    <a target="_blank" href="#">link</a>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see, when you click out of `div#myid` element, an alert will be shown. I want that alert also be shown when you click on the `link`. How can I do that?

Comment: Add a condition to check whether the event target was the link …?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @stack - please add additional check to your target and check if its link. See my answer. I have fixed your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you can add another condition to your if which excludes the `a` element inside the `#myid` element. Try this:

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if ($target.closest("#myid").length > 0 && $target.is(':not(a)')) {
    return false;
  }
  alert('clicked');
});
```

```css
#myid {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="myid">
    something <br>
    <a target="_blank" href="#">link</a>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One question, `$(e.target)` is the same as `$(this)` ?

Comment: Nope. Here $(this) means $(document) as you are attaching an event to $(document)

Comment: @stack No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I've added another check as follows:

```
 if( $(e.target).closest("#myid").length > 0 && $(e.target).attr("id") !=="linkID")
```

Add id attribute to your link as:

```
<a target="_blank" id="linkID" href="#">link</a>
```

Please see the fiddle. Its working fine

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
  if( $(e.target).closest("#myid").length > 0 && $(e.target).attr("id") !=="linkID") {
    return false;
  }
  alert('clicked');
});
```

```css
#myid{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="myid">
    something <br>
    <a target="_blank" id="linkID" href="#">link</a>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the current target that you clicked. In this case you need to distinguish from the current target (which will be the anchor) before anything else.

You can tell which element you clicked using the `.is()` [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
Example:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is("a")){
    alert("You clicked the anchor");
    e.stopPropagation();
    return;
  }

  if ($(e.target).closest("#myid").length > 0) {
    return false;
  }

  alert('clicked');
});
```

I added a condition before proceeding to check if the clicked element is an anchor element. Better add something to select it uniquely, like a class or an Id.

I use the `.is()` method which returns true or false based on the condition you pass for interrogating a particular DOM element. In this case I check if the element is an anchor tag. Note, I use `.stopPropagation()` [method](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to prevent the event from bubbling up, this is not needed in this particular case, but it is a good practice in such situations, as you might end up with unexpected behavior. Lastly, don't forget to return in order to avoid executing the code that follows.

If you don't need to keep the anchor's default behavior, i.e. don't want to navigate to the location designated in the `href` attribute, just prevent that  using the [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method or returning `false`.

Check on fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mrgwx73b/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add an event listener to `#myid`?

```js
$('#myid').on('click', function(event) {
  alert('clicked');
})
```

```css
#myid{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="myid">
    something <br>
    <a target="_blank" href="#">link</a>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This logic is opposite to what the OP is trying to do

Comment: He wants to fire an alert when `#myid` is clicked and also when the `link` inside `#myid` is clicked. Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, he wants to show the alert when you click the `a` or anywhere *except* `#myid`